# Cron expression for only for wednesday every after 2 hours

Tags: cronexpression

java - Spring, i want to crate cron expression to run every after 2 hours only on Wednesday till day end

```
0 0 0/2 * * WED *
```

mean cron should trigger every wednessday only for these times 2am, 4am, 6am, 8am,10am, 12pm, 2pm,4pm, 6pm, 8pm, 10pm, 12pm

i don't have time long to wait and test can some one please confirm is it correct ?

Comment: What does "every after 2 hours" mean exactly?

Comment: mean cron should trigger every wednessday only for these times and 2am, 4am, 6am, 8am,10am, 12pm, 2pm,4pm, 6pm, 8pm, 10pm, 12pm

Comment: Is this a quartz scheduler cron expression?

Answer (score 0):

Even though it is way to late i like to answer the question for other users.

Your CronExpression is invalid. You can check this [here](http://www.cronmaker.com/) or [here](https://www.freeformatter.com/cron-expression-generator-quartz.html). The problem is: You cannot specify a day_of_month AND a day_of_week.

Cause you are setting a day_of_week you should skip day_of_month with a "?". Solution should be: 
`0 0 0/2 ? * WED *`